# C++ Exclude classes inherited through base class in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++, is it possible to exclude a class inherited in the base class, from a subclass?

For example, if you have three classes like so:

```cpp
class A
{
public:

    int x;
};

class B : public A
{
public:

    int y;
};

class C : public B
{
public:

    int z;
};
```

Is it possible for class `B` to contain the variables `x` and `y`, while class `C` only contains `y` and `z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you want to achieve is private inheritance.

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B : private A
{
    int y;
};

struct C : B
{
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.x = 5; // error. you're not allowed to access members from A
    c.y = 3; // ok
    c.z = 4; // ok
}
```

So the data of A is still going to be there but you just can't access it from outside of B.

If you want the data to not exist in C at all then the answer is No. Inheritance is literally having the content of your parents in the beginning of your struct.

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B : A
{
    int y;
};
```

in memory an instance of B will look like this:

```
struct B
{
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

Comment: I was about to say "No," then I saw your answer about private inheritance. Excellent. Wish I could up-vote more.

Comment: Thank you :D I was about to say "No" myself but @Javier Silva Ortíz 's answer inspired mine. While his answer seems a bit far-fetched, it does solve the problem. he deserves more up-votes IMO :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to meet your variable inheritance constraints. Use [friend](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/amp/) classes. With the friendship semantics exposed by the keyword `friend` inside a class declaration, you can make a derived class to have access to the private members of its parent class. The link contains a full tutorial of the friendship semantics.

Your code would look like:

```
class A
{
private:

    int x;
    friend class B;
};

class B : public A
{
public:

    int y;
};

class C : public B
{
public:

    int z;
};
```

With this, `class B` has access to the `private x` of `class A`,  but only from inside the definition of `class B`. Your variable inheritance constraint is met, `class B` contains (and can use) `x` and `y`, while `class C` contains `y` and `z`.

Another way could be by private inheritance, like this:

```
class A
{
private:

    int x;
};

class B : private A
{
public:

    int y;
};

class C : public B
{
public:

    int z;
};
```

But this is much more stricter than the `friend` approach. Choose which one suits your need.